# Split string with parenthesis within parenthesis in Python

Tags: python, regex, string, substring

I have two strings types; each type can have one of the following exemplary forms:

```
str = ((0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9))
```

or

```
str = ((0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5, 6, 7), (8, 9))
```

The number of substrings within parentheses in the second form can range from 1 to any number.

I need a) to be able to detect the presence of each form, and b) if the string has the second form I need to extract each of the substrings within each of the inner parenthesis.

I have a basic understanding of regular expressions but I can't see how this should be handled.

Comment: Why do you need a regex? They're valid tuples, just `ast.literal_eval` them.

Comment: On another note, you shouldn't name your variable `str`. That overrides the built-in.

Comment: Ugliest hack I can think of :`[s[:s.index(')')] for s in str[1:-1].split('(') if s]` ... strangely it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

If these are the only two options you can use:

```
if type(str[0]) == int:
   print 'TYPE1'
else if type(str[0]) == tuple:
   print 'TYPE2'
else:
   print 'unknown'
```

and for your second question, in case you're in form 2, use:

```
list(sum(str, ()))
```

to flatten the tuple, this way you can access every element individually.

If you want to access the tuples as whole, you can use:

```
for element in str:
   #element is an inner tuple
   for inner_element in element:
       #inner_element is an integer within the tuple
       print inner_element
```

Hope this helps